# Defining 2D arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
int train [4] [3] = {   0, 0, 0,
                                      0, 1, 0,
                                      1, 0, 0,
                                      1, 1, 1 };
```

Is that a valid initialization of a 2d array in C++

And the rows will be 0,0,0 (row 1), (0,1,0) (row2), (1,0,0) (row3) and (1,1,1) (row 4) ?

And is it equivalent to

```
 int train [4] [3] = {{0, 0, 0},
                       {0, 1, 0},
                       {1, 0, 0},
                       {1, 1, 1}};
```

Comment: Why just write the equivalent version - as it works!

Comment: It should be very easy to check, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! It is a valid intialization  in c++.

Answer (score 7):

```
int train [4] [3] = {   0, 0, 0,
                        0, 1, 0,
                        1, 0, 0,
                        1, 1, 1 };
```

is a valid initialization of a 2D array in C++.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **8.5.1 Aggregates**
>
> 10 When initializing a multi-dimensional array, the initializer-clauses initialize the elements with the last (right-most) index of the array varying the fastest (8.3.4). [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> int x[2][2] = { 3, 1, 4, 2 };
> ```
>
> initializes `x[0][0]` to `3`, `x[0][1]` to `1`, `x[1][0]` to `4`, and `x[1][1]` to `2`. On the other hand,
>
> ```
> float y[4][3] = {
>   { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 4 }
> };
> ```

initializes the first column of `y` (regarded as a two-dimensional array) and leaves the rest zero. — *end example* ]